# devcontainer.json property service/dockerComposeFile is not allowed

Tags: visual-studio-code

After an update of VSCode, there are certain properties in devcontainer.json that seem to be no longer working.

```
...
"dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
"service": "rover",
...
```

Both of the above properties have a yellow underline with the following prompt:
`Property x is not allowed`
x = dockerComposeFile / service

I've tried to look around for alternatives but to be honest not really finding much.
**Question:**
Has anyone been able to find a way to implement these settings?

**Extra info:**
The devcontainer documentation doesn't seem to have been updated either as it still references the two properties:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference

Current "about" of VSCode:

```
Version: 1.60.1 (user setup)
Commit: 83bd43bc519d15e50c4272c6cf5c1479df196a4d
Date: 2021-09-10T17:07:10.714Z
Electron: 13.1.8
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042
```

Comment: Just bumped into the same issue. Have you got any clues?

Comment: If you have a `workspaceMount`, `runArgs`, or `mounts` key in there, it will cause you to see that error. There are likely some other keys that cause this. I ran into this exact issue myself just now.

Comment: @JeffThompson s suggestion worked for me, commented out 'workspaceMount' and the warning was gone.

Comment: Thanks @JeffThompson that worked for me, except I had to comment out ```runArgs``` too.

Answer (score 0):

"dockerComposeFile" in mine works as a list, like:

```
"dockerComposeFile": ["docker-compose.yaml"],
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is clear -- the dockerComposeFile key expects an array, not a string, so just surround the "docker-compose.yml" string with square brackets -- [].

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, put your code explicitly in the code block. It'll help the author and new readers.